# Расшифровка файла p7s.p7m, sig.enc

Tags: .net, криптография, гост

Как расшифровать файл созданный АРМ Крипто ПРО версии 4 по алгоритму ГОСТ 28147-89?

Какая используется таблица замен?

Какой ключ используется для шифрования и расшифрования? Стандартная длинна ключа 28147-89 256 bit. Когда я открываю информацию о своем приватном ключе его длинна 512 bit.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection collection =
                (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
            IDecryptable decoder = new AESCryptoDecoder();
var size = collection[0].PrivateKey.KeySize;// 512 bit
```

Comment: вот здесь есть что то , что можно почитать  
https://habrahabr.ru/post/256843/  и тут кое что 
https://habrahabr.ru/post/81032/

Comment: Здесь у вас что-то не так. Алгоритм ГОСТ 28147-89 это симметричный шифр, а кусок кода это из асимметричного шифра :)

Comment: Да не важно. Я этот пример использовал что бы только узнать длину ключа.  В общем решил из программы вызывать утилиту cryptcp. Она дублирует функции АРМ Крипто про